# Simply opening only one tab at window.open

Tags: javascript

For example, my `html` file:

```
<script>
    window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/');
</script>
```

I [run my file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfaTR.gif). I want that only *Stack Overflow* tab opened. I don't want that tab before the *Stack Overflow* tab opened. What do I have to make? Without use the server.

Comment: Usually it should open Stack Overflow in a new tab only, without opening your "file://..." tab. Do you have any other anchor/JS inside the HTML? If you just test your JS in jsfiddle for example it is working right. Without your complete code it's hard to find the solution.

Comment: @mxl The new window is the window which runs the script. It isn't closed.

Comment: You're right. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **window.location.href** to load within the current tab.

```
window.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com';
```

Comment: Thanks, it work! Unfortunately, if I specify some URL, only the last URL opens. `<script>
    window.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com';
    window.location.href='http://ru.stackoverflow.com';
</script>` doesn't work, open only last URL.

Comment: It is intended to work only for a single URL, not for multiple URL's.

Comment: Arun CM, and what I have to do if URL is a lot of? (Yes, I understand that it I had to specify it in my question.)

Comment: @NicoleJoraanstad please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aruncm/3devhcwr/ , let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: Arun CM, yes, it work! How to remake this script that tabs were opened not when pressing by clicking the link, and after opening of the file on my computer? I open the `Example.html` file and at me in the browser 3 web pages are opened: `stackoverflow.com`, `jsfiddle.net` and `google.com`?

Comment: @NicoleJoraanstad Write the code inside a "documet.ready" instead of "click" event, Check this Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/aruncm/3devhcwr/1/  It will open the URL's as soon as you open the Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

This obviously happens because the window which runs your script isn't closed after the script is run. Then you should close the window.

```
<script>
    window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/');
    window.close();
</script>
```

Comment: Occurs nothing( . Still 2 tabs open.

Comment: @Nicole What browser are you using?

Comment: Nicael, Pale Moon 26.3.3 (latest version).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href="http://stackoverflow.com/"` in on load function